# How to overlap plot in python?

Tags: python, plot

I have a program to plot some values.

I want to change some values in my script and plot it overlap.

How can i do it?

Thanks

plot in python

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you doing it? Using matplotlib? Showing a sample of you code helps.

Answer (score 1):

You just do it again.

For instance, if you did:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,z, etc)
plt.scatter(x1,y1,z1, etc)
```

You'd get a plot with both of those.

You may want to specify the colors of the second one because otherwise, it will start over with the first color it would use.

I regularly plot a contour over a contourf that way.